# Handle delete and update by comparing two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having two tables which i would like to compare in that sense that if the `circuitId` is the identical in the two columns it should check if CHECKSUM column is the same if they are the same do nothing else insert a new record into the table. If the `circiutId` is not present in the table it should add a new row aswell.

So far i have this, but i'm not sure how to implement so that inside  the logic in `WHEN MATCHED THEN`. so that it inside that checks whether checksum is the same aswell and thereby from that insert a record?

```
MERGE INTO ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS n
        USING EXTRACT.F1_CIRCUITS o
        ON
        (n.CIRCUITID= o."circuitId")
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT VALUES
            ("circuitId","circuitRef","name","location","country","lat","lng","alt","url", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, HASH_MD5("circuitId","circuitRef","name","location","country","lat","lng","alt","url"), 'C', 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `insert` is sufficient:

```
INSERT INTO ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS ( . . . )
    SELECT . . . 
    FROM EXTRACT.F1_CIRCUITS o
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM ARCHIVE.F1_CIRCUITS n
                      WHERE o.circuitid = n.circuitid AND
                            o.checksum = n.checksum
                     );
```

The `. . .` is for the various column names and expressions.